# C++ Array Input and Exit Validation

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, visual-c++, validation

I'm not sure what's wrong with my approach to inputting an unlimited amount of item prices.  However, the biggest concern is when I press zero (the way it needs to terminate with), the inputting does not halt and the final outputs are not displayed.  Any direction in a better approach would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int MAX=8;
bool check=true;
double  totalPrice, discount, discountedPrice;
double *prices = new double[];

cout<<"Enter the price of your items.";
cout<<"Enter zero (0) when you have finished entering all the items.\n\n";

while(check==true)
{

for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{

    cout<<"Enter the price of item "<<i<<": ";
    cin>>prices[i];

if(cin==0){

    check=false;


    break;

}
}

    if(prices==0)
    {
        check=false;
        break;

        for(int j=0; j<sizeof(prices);j++)
        {
            totalPrice+=prices[j];  
        }

        discount=totalPrice*.075;
        discountedPrice=totalPrice-discount;

        cout<<"The total price of your "<<sizeof(prices)<<"items is: $"<<totalPrice;
        cout<<"Discount of your "<<sizeof(prices)<<"is: $"<<discount;
        cout<<"\nThe discounted price of your "<<sizeof(prices)<<"is: $"<<discountedPrice;
    }
}

cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a vector for something that resizes itself for you.

Comment: The array seems to be fine, I checked that.  However, I can't get the input of zero to terminate the loop.  I want it to be as simple as possible please.

Comment: Well, `double *prices = new double[];` isn't even valid syntax.

Comment: What do you suggest?  This array needs to handle decimal values and it has worked so far.

Comment: I already suggested `std::vector`. I don't know if this is an MSVC extension, but a vector does that just fine with `push_back` or whatever insertion method you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

;It should be `if(prices[i] == 0){ check = false; break; }`

Comment: Thank you, after messing around with it, your logic worked good.

Answer (score 1):

```
 cout<<"Enter the price of item "<<i<<": ";
    int temp;
    cin>>temp;
if(temp == 0){

    check=false;


    break;

}
```

Should fix this issue, and it won't put a zero in the prices array.